# Application Preferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using default application preferences to store information related to my app. Basically I want to store information in preferences even if the app get deleted. Is using default preference the best way to accomplish this. Any help appreciated.
This is the code I am using

```
//--Init
int myvar = 12;


//--SAVE Data
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);  
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("var1", myvar);
editor.commit();


//--READ data       
myvar = preferences.getInt("var1", 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information will not be saved if the app is deleted.

One option you have is to save such information to a file, but even then the user will be able to delete it.

If you try to implement some trial version, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029051/how-to-implement-trialware-model-on-android/).